# How to manage workforce allocation in retail store using Linear Programming?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, linear-programming, resource-scheduling

How can I create such a model that automatically allocates available labors into each department according to the current workload each of them respectively.

Lets suppose in a retail store there are lot of people for billing to automatically model must allocate more labors into cashier and after sometime when the traffic become low some of the cashier must be allocated to any other department like picking or arranging things and so on with the available labors on the same day . So can we do it using Linear Programming if yes then can you please provide me the suggestion else can you please let me know what kind of problem is it and any reference towards it will be appreciated.

Comment: This is quite a general question about linear programming in general. You may get better responses from people if the question is about a specific issue such as a line of code that isn't working.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The goal is achievable. You will want to use pulp for this https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/

Its a fairly standard application of LP and there are a number of resources and tutorials available from the above link which should guide you to a solution but you will need to adapt to suit your particular needs.